# Telnet using Python

Tags: python, telnet

hi I am new to python and I am trying to telenet to my host connected via Host-only adapter :

My command are

```
  import telnetlib
import time


def call_func():
    time1 = 2
    connect = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.1.100',23,3)
    connect.write('show version'.encode('ascii'))
    time.sleep(time1)
    print (connect.read_very_eager().decode('ascii'))
    connect.close()


call_func()
```

However I am not able to read the full output of the show version command. Can someone explain why I am not able to do so?

Output got:
'R1>show version'

Answer (score 0):

You can read about all `read_` methods in [telnetlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) and compare their outputs. It states there, that only `read_until()` will give you text "until a given byte string". All of the other ones will return only "all data until EOF", "everything that can be without blocking in I/O", "readily available data." etc.

That said, you should use `read_until()` to be sure you get a full string returned. This in the only method that waits for telnet to return the whole text.

Additional explanation can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/9hF6vMYDErk/h9BKtfCAMz0J) in a similar question.